# Why I cannot modify the result object

Tags: sequelize.js

Why the objects returned by sequelize `findAll` and the likes cannot be modified like regular objects? I checked if they are frozen or locked, but `Object.isFrozen()` returns false. Does it use getters instead of real properties (how do I check that?)

So far my only option to modify the results is to do `JSON.parse(JSON.strigify(result))` which is OK, but incurs performance price.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your instances have getters and setters methods. You can call instance.get('field') or instance.set('field', value).

But If you are trying to dynamically add a new property to your model, you can try to create a property type : DataTypes.VIRTUAL.

DataTypes.VIRTUAL properties are transients, you can use to customize/add properties value that you dont want to be persisted to database.

http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/v3/api/datatypes/#virtual